# GetTerminalSize: How do I have to modify a handle to get a different output?

Tags: perl, terminal, console, size, filehandle

In which cases would setting the file handle explicitly change the result of [Term::ReadKey](https://metacpan.org/pod/Term%3a%3aReadKey)::GetTerminalSize?

```
use Term::ReadKey qw( GetTerminalSize );

open my $fh, '>', 'TEST.txt' or die $!;
select( $fh );

my ( $c, $d ) = GetTerminalSize( $fh );
my ( $j, $k ) = GetTerminalSize();

# both the same size:
say STDOUT "FILE: $c x $d";
say STDOUT "OUT:  $j x $k";
```

---

Redirected STDOUT to a file but still the same size:

```
use Term::ReadKey qw( GetTerminalSize );

my ( $c, $d ) = GetTerminalSize( \*STDOUT );
my ( $j, $k ) = GetTerminalSize( \*STDERR );

# same size:
say STDERR "OUT: $c x $d";
say STDERR "ERR: $j x $k";
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Windows:

> Under Windows, this function must be called with an "output" filehandle,
>   such as STDOUT, or a handle opened to CONOUT$.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense.

First off, why are you expecting to request the terminal size of a non-terminal filehandle? Regular files do not have a size.

Secondly, one-argument `select()` simply chooses the default output handle for a `print` or `say` statement with no filehandle given. It's an old anachronism and shouldn't be used in modern code.

Comment: Are there cases where `GetTerminalSize` called with `STDERR` instead of `STDOUT` would return different values?

Comment: Sure; if they're both attached to different filehandles. Most likely scenario is if the perl program was run with STDOUT redirected, but STDERR remains on the actual controlling terminal.

Comment: I tried that already but I didn't see any difference. I added the example.